# AnkhSVN commit/needs update issue

Tags: commit, ankhsvn

I have AnkhSvn plugged in to Visual Studio 2008.

When I try to commit several files, and at least one of those files causes the prompt to Update, I would like to know which of those files has caused it.

Currently, I am highlighting the files in Pending Changes, Right click and Show Changes, and change the options so it is FROM Base TO Latest.  Any files which are not identical have therefore got new content so need to be updated.  This is unwieldy (to say the least) so was wondering if there is a quick way of seeing which files have prompted the "needs update" message.

Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In Pending Changes click the "Recent Changes" tab, and press the refresh button here, refreshes aren't scheduled (yet). Here you see your changes as well as the changes on the server. You're looking for files that are changed both locally and on the server (marked with <->).

It's usually a better idea to update all files often than it is to update individual files, you'll end up with less conflicts that way.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!  

Do you know if you can add a hook so when you go to edit a file Ankh can check if you have an old version and if so alert you to this? 

Also, we are currently reading: http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/pages/3267-general
http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

can you recommend any other resources/blogs etc?

Cheers!

Guillaume

Comment: You can't add a hook like that. The tricky part is also that a new version can be checked in while you are working. To cope with this you would pretty much need to constantly scan the remote status, which also breaks offline capability.
As for other resources, be sure to check out the svnbook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/